# error at tinyxml when deserialize

Tags: c++, tinyxml

I have the following `xml:`

```
<Name />
<Sur> mmm </Sur>
```

When I deserialize I wrote:

```
TiXmlElement* section;
section=handle.FirstChild("Name").ToElement()
if (section) {}
```

The problem is that the if condition is runned though `field Name is null`. WHY? Where am I wrong?
Appreciate. THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should define a root element of your XML code, like `<Person>`:

```
<Person>
    <Name />
    <Sur> mmm <Sur />
</Person>
```